# Are BigQuery Data Transfer Service dataset copies transactional?

Tags: google-bigquery

When using the BigQuery Data Transfer Service to copy a BigQuery dataset to another BigQuery dataset, will the new backup dataset preserve the **entire** state of every table as of the commencement of the backup process?

IOW, will the copy preserve the state of every table in the source dataset as of the time the transfer commenced? Or, if changes are made to some source tables after the commencement of the copying process, will those changes be copied too?

The only doc I could locate on the topic is [on this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#copy-datasets), and reads:

> The destination table might not reflect changes made to the source tables after a copy job starts.

... and I'm hoping for something a bit stronger than "might not".  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The description of the copy function is possibly because this on beta phase at the moment. Please see [link](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) here for Product launch stages.

> The destination table might not reflect changes made to the source tables after a copy job starts.

BQ's [data transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction) purpose is to automate data movement to BigQuery. You can try to initiate backfills if there is gaps on after your scheduled run.

I would suggest to watch out for BQ's release note page for updates in the API. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes

**UPDATE:** Made a Feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/302346038

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the gaps I'm concerned about.  I'm just wondering if the Data Transfer Service takes a "snapshot" of all data in all tables at the time the process starts, or if, instead, changes made to some tables after the transfer starts will be transferred too.

Comment: I don't believe BigQuery Data Transfer can apply changes from the source table mid process, Changes may apply for the next run of a transfer job.  However I have updated the answer as I made a Feature Request of your inquiry, for a possibility to gain traction for other users and can verify if its possible.